# Why do I get error "handler and runtime must be set when PackageType is Zip" when using terraform to configure image container lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a lambda function using an image URI, but getting an error as if I'm trying to create a zip package type lambda.

getting the error: "handler and runtime must be set when PackageType is Zip"

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
    image_uri   = "<my_ecr_uri>"
    function_name = "my_function_name"
    role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
    architectures = ["x86_64"]

    image_config {
        command = ["handler.sh"]
        entry_point = ["/bin/sh"]
        working_directory = "/usr/src"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a container image, you must also set [package_type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#package_type):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
    package_type = Image
    image_uri   = "<my_ecr_uri>"
    function_name = "my_function_name"
    role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
    architectures = ["x86_64"]

    image_config {
        command = ["handler.sh"]
        entry_point = ["/bin/sh"]
        working_directory = "/usr/src"
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but note that the word "Image" should be put between double quotes: `package_type = "Image"`